# PayPal IPN not working using Sandbox account in Kentico Version 10

Tags: paypal, kentico

I am trying test the PayPal IPN after the payment, but it never worked in my Kentico project.
I am able to call the IPN page from PayPal IPN simulator but when I do the payment using Sandbox it doesn't work!

- IPN is enabled in PayPal sandbox account (Business)
- I am passing the correct notify URL
- Notify URL is publicly accessible and working with valid certificate (https)
- CSRF is disabled
- Testing for Recurring payment

is there anything more I need to do or verify

Version: Kentico 10

Thanks,
Sharath

Comment: are you on any hotfix for v10? there was an bug that's been fixed in 10.0.3 hotfix.  Security - Payments made via the PayPal payment gateway causing errors. Due to a misconfiguration of the system's CSRF protection, an error ocurred when verifying payments that were made using the PayPal payment gateway. As a result, the payment was aborted and the order not marked as paid.

Comment: Also, can PayPal reach back to your testing server? If your server is only local, you can't get this work. The server has to be publicly accessible in order for the test to work.